# Tunnel a localhost subdirectory through ngrok?

Tags: http, localhost, wamp, virtualhost, ngrok

Objective: want to share a website preview using ngrok, which creates a tunnel from which my localhost can be seen with an url of something like `mywebsite.ngrok.io`

Problem: I use WAMP and my localhost folder looks something like this:

```
localhostdirectory
   |-- website1
   |-- website2
   |-- etc
```

To access a website I type to `localhost/website1/` in the browser, I would like to tunnel only that URL, the possible solutions would be:

1. Setting up a Virtual host, [I would go through the hassle of manually setting up a virtual host](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757), then I get something like website1.dev, and then I would pass it to ngrok as the host header in the HTTP request, [like that](https://ngrok.com/docs#host-header):

   ```
   ngrok http -host-header=website1.dev 80
   ```

   I didn't understand what the host header is though, and why can't I pass a relative url like `localhost/website1/`, also what is the rewrite option?
2. Change the folder directory of my localhost to the folder of the website, I would prefer not to do that.

Is there a better way to accomplish my objective in an easier way, maybe going through WAMP aliases?

Comment: Virtual hosts are not that **frightening** see this for how to setup. Once you have done the first one it should be a 2 minute job to do the next. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Yes you just have to add some text in the httpd-vhosts.conf file and then in the hosts file, but that's still a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you make do with Apache Vhost you just have to exec command

`ngrok http -host-header=rewrite YOUR-LOCAL-DOMAIN:PORT`

Dont forgot to edit host file for resolution @IP <-> YOUR-LOCAL-DOMAIN

Comment: This worked for me with a subdomain. Ex: `sub.local.dev` Thanks!

Comment: If this does not work for you, try: `ngrok http -host-header=SUBDOMAIN.localhost PORT`

Comment: Work for me : `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite YOUR-LOCAL-DOMAIN:PORT`

Answer (score 16):

I tried below way.

When I ran `$ ./ngrok http 80`  ngrok listen to `localhost:80` which shows dashboard because apache server is running on `port 80`. Then I tried running subfolder in another port, which solved problem. Assume you have project in `xyz` and want ngrok should points it. Then do following

```
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

Here `8080` is any unused port. `localhost:8080` direct points to `xyz` and then open other terminal

`$ ./ngrok http 8080`

By doing this ngrok will listen to `8080` port were your `xyz` is running.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have tried this on Wordpress, I can open a page at xxxxx.ngrok.io with browser but on mobile it shows only text without images and styles

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: If you don't see images and CSS styles, you might have https errors in the console, try using the http link instead.

Comment: Saved me writing a SO question. I was trying to get ngrok to point to a subdirectory on my localhost and tried all kinds of things with the -host-header option to ultimately have `php -S localhost:8080` (in the subdirectory) save the day so i could then do `ngrok http 8080` 

Answer (score 5):

I believe the correct syntax now for ngrok v3 is `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite YOUR-LOCAL-DOMAIN:PORT`

Notice the double `--`

https://ngrok.com/docs/guides/upgrade-v2-v3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

After you set up the ngrok address to point to localhost on port 80, you can access your websites by their names.
Ex:

```
ngrok http -subdomain=dev 80
```

Access website1:

```
dev.ngrok.io/website1
```

Comment: This only works in combination with a paid subscription for ngrok.