# how to rewrite -host-header in ngrok in order to open a sub-website in xampp running on localhost

Tags: php, http, xampp, localhost, ngrok

I am trying to expose my website to internet, using ngrok, my website lives in xampp server which is running on my local machine.
 the path to my website is this:
 **C:\xampp\htdocs\TheWebsite**
when i use the following command for running ngrok client:

**ngrok http -host-header=rewrite TheWebsite:8081**

the client gets connected to ngrok server, but when i try to access my website on internet using http://234k2h4k24.ngrok.io which is the url ngrok provides for me, i end up with this error:
***The connection to http://234k2h4k24.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address TheWebsite:8081.
Make sure that a web service is running on TheWebsite:8081 and that it is a valid address.
The error encountered was: dial tcp: lookup TheWebsite: no such host***
how exactly one should set the value for **-host-header** *switch* in order to to get the sub-directories (websites) living in htdocs folder in xampp server environment??
I have searched this site and also all over the Internet and i found some quick answers but they confused me even more.
 like this one:
https://helgesverre.com/blog/expose-local-webserver/ 
which doesn't even provide a small example 
and this:    [Tunnel a localhost subdirectory through ngrok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017319/tunnel-a-localhost-subdirectory-through-ngrok) 
 
just the same as previous one (no example)
A real good answer needs to provide at least one complete example (i mean, if you want to answer this question, please provide a full example of ngrok command for the path of my website (**TheWebsite**). thank you

Answer (score 0):

**for this purpose i needed to define virtual hosts for each of my websites!**

I found the answer in a related question at stackoverflow.com and here it is:
[Tunnel a localhost subdirectory through ngrok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017319/tunnel-a-localhost-subdirectory-through-ngrok?noredirect=1&lq=1)

this question leads you to this page which lets you know how to define virtual hosts in order for your local machine to identify where is the requested website, just take a look and you will learn in it no time.
 here is the page:
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

although its for wamp but it is the same for xampp server too!