# How to set a path when connecting to tunnel?

Tags: ngrok

When starting `ngrok` tunnel it requires a port, host, or subdomain with the host. Example: `ngrok http localhost:8000`.

I'd like to point/bind the tunnel not to a port or a host but to a specific path on my host. such `localhost:8000/webhook`. I tried it and it looks like it's not possible. Is there any alternative way of doing what I want?

Comment: I guess its a duplicate of : [Tunnel to specific host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017319/tunnel-a-localhost-subdirectory-through-ngrok?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command:

`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite YOUR-LOCAL-DOMAIN:PORT`

so, with your example : `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite localhost:8000/webhook`

It should do the job.

Comment: It doesn't work :/ `ERROR:  Tunnel 'command_line' specifies a path '/webhook', this is unsupported`

Comment: do you have another service to expose the website under the hood?

Comment: No, I don't have.